How evaluate :$\int^1_0 \ln\left({x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}\right)dx$

How to evaluate :$$I=\int^1_0 \ln\left({x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}\right)dx$$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
I & =\int^1_0 \ln\left({x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}\right)dx
\\[2mm] & = \int^1_0 \ln\left({x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx
\end{align*}
Hence:
$$2I=\int^1_0 \ln\left({x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx$$
How do I continue to answer?

Have you tried it with any software?

You sure it is convergent?

\begin{align}
&\int^1_0 \ln\left({x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}\ dx\\
=& \int^1_0 \sinh^{-1}x\ \cosh^{-1}\frac1x\ \overset{ibp} {dx}\\
=&\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
 -\int_0^1 \frac{x\cosh^{-1}\frac1x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\\
=& \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac x{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+x^2y^2)}}dy\ dx\\
&\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>-\int_0^1 {\cosh^{-1}\frac1x}\  \overset{ibp} d\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\right)\\
=&\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}y}{y}dy -\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
=& \ G -\left(\frac\pi4 -\frac12\ln2\right)
\end{align}

Too Long to be a comment:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x
& = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+1)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\sqrt{1+x}+1)\sqrt{1-x}} \\
& = \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sqrt{1-\sin x}} \mathrm{d}x\\
& = \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2\!\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\!\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\!\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\!\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}} \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}x - \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2}+1} \\
& = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\sin\frac{x}{4}\cos\frac{x}{4}+2\cos^2\!\frac{x}{4}} \\
& = \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}\tan\frac{x}{4}}{\tan\frac{x}{4}+1} \\
& = \frac{\pi}{4}-\ln\left(1+\tan\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln2}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Integration by parts yields
$$
\int \ln \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right) d x=x \ln \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\sqrt{1+x^2}+C \\
\textrm{ and }\\ \frac{d}{d x} \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)=-\frac{1}{x \sqrt{1-x^2}} \tag*{} 
$$
Using integration by parts again gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_0^1 \ln \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right) \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right) d x \\
= & \int_0^1 \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right) d\left[x \ln \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\right)\right]\\=&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x-\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x \sqrt{1-x^2}} d x\\=& \int_0^1 \frac{\sinh ^{-1} x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\right) (\textrm{ Via } x=\sin \theta )\\=&G-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\ln 2}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $G=\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh ^{-1} x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ is the Catalan’s constant.
Wish it helps.

Rewrite the logarithms as hyperbolic functions, then exploit Fubini's theorem:
$$\newcommand{arsinh}{\operatorname{arsinh}}
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \arsinh x \operatorname{arsech}x \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \frac{\arsinh x}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^y \cdots dx\,dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+y^2} + y \arsinh y}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy & \text{by parts} \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt{1+y^2}}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy + \int_0^1 \frac{\arsinh y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy
\end{align*}$$
A variety of trig/hyperbolic substitutions can be applied to the first integral to show
$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1-\sqrt{1+y^2}}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy &= \frac12 \operatorname{arsech}y^2 - \frac12 \arcsin y^2 - \operatorname{arsech} y + C \\
\implies \int_0^1 \cdots dy &= \frac12\log2 - \frac\pi4
\end{align*}$$
The latter integral is a known form of Catalan's constant.
